# C++11 std::unique_ptr deleter

Tags: c++, linux, c++11

I used the codes as follow, but g++ give me errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory>

using Func = void (*)(void *p);

class A {
};

class B {
    std::unique_ptr<A, Func> b = std::unique_ptr<A, Func>(nullptr, nullptr);
};

int main()
{

}
```

g++ error messages.

```
test.cc:10:50: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
std::unique_ptr<A, Func> b = std::unique_ptr<A, Func>(nullptr, nullptr);
                                              ^
test.cc:10:50: error: declaration of ‘std::unique_ptr<A, void (*)(void*)> B::Func’ [-fpermissive]
test.cc:4:31: error: changes meaning of ‘Func’ from ‘using Func = void (*)(void*)’ [-fpermissive]
using Func = void (*)(void *p);
                           ^
test.cc:10:54: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘>’ token
std::unique_ptr<A, Func> b = std::unique_ptr<A, Func>(nullptr, nullptr);
                                                  ^
test.cc:10:47: error: template argument 1 is invalid
std::unique_ptr<A, Func> b = std::unique_ptr<A, Func>(nullptr, nullptr);
                                           ^
test.cc:10:47: error: template argument 2 is invalid
```

g++ version

```
root@ubuntu-linux:~/trafficserver/iocore/net/quic# g++ test.cc -std=c++11^C
root@ubuntu-linux:~/trafficserver/iocore/net/quic# g++ -v
gcc version 4.9.4 (Ubuntu 4.9.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1)
```

It seems like bad delete function.

Comment: Yes, `nullptr` is not a valid deleter function. What did you expect?

Comment: @nwp `nullptr` won't work as a deleter, but it is a legal value for a `Func` argument as far as the type system is concerned.

Comment: [cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d1850766f424f41f)

Answer (score 3):

This may be a compiler bug. You are using an older version of gcc. gcc.5.4 produces the same compilation error but [gcc 6.1 works fine](https://godbolt.org/g/ZrnA7G). If you replace `Func` with `void (*)(void *)` directly, it seems to compile. It also seems to work if you define an alias for `std::unique_ptr<A, Func>`.

You should upgrade your compiler. If that's not possible for you, as a work around, you can try the following :

```
#include <memory>

class A {
};

using Func = void (*)(void *);
using MyPtr = std::unique_ptr<A, Func>;

class B {
    MyPtr b = MyPtr(nullptr, nullptr);
};
```

Comment: I update the gcc version and this issue goes away. But there is another problem with ASAN `unrecognized option '--push-state'` . So I updated code as above. It works well, Definetly Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your code is kind of fine. It is too modern for g++ 4.9. Here's how you do it with g++ 4.9

```
class A {
};

void Func(void*) {

}

class B {
  std::unique_ptr<A, decltype(&Func)> b = 
    std::unique_ptr<A, decltype(&Func)>(nullptr, nullptr);
};

int main(){

}
```